# How to make a fluid box transition

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, animation

I want when you click in the radio button for change the content, and when the box change the height, have a fluid transition. I have tried with transition property but don't work =/

[MY CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/FelipeMartinin/URU86/6/)

```
.main-form-show {
     background: #fff;
     padding: 20px;
     max-width: 500px;
     margin: auto;
     border-radius: 10px;
     margin-top: 250px;
     transition: 1s;
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any fiddle with your own code? so we can figure out what's wrong with your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FelipeMartinin/URU86/6/

Comment: oh is that your code! i thought that is a demo. btw it works like charm!, it adjusts heights as you wanted?

Comment: How you can see, when you select another radio button, the content change, alright? And the height of box change too. What i want is a fluid height change. I tried with the transition property but don't work

Comment: what do you mean by fluid height change? you want smooth transition of height?

Comment: exactly. like that -> http://www.hipmunk.com/

Comment: i can really help you but the problem is i didn't understand fluid thing. the given  hipmunk.com shows a fixed height box with tabs. the height of the box stays still and other content changes when the button click. but here you mean fluid and giving me hipmunk.com. that is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be done:

1. Get the height of the div to be displayed (while it is still
   hidden).
2. Set the height of the div to be displayed to the height of the currently displayed div.
3. Hide the currently displayed div.
4. Show the new div.
5. Animate the height of the new div to what it really should be (which is what was obtained in the first step).

I do not believe all browsers support getting the height of a hidden div, so the following code is a work-around:

```
$div.css({ position: 'absolute', visibility: 'hidden', display: 'block' });
var height = $div.height();
$div.css({ position: 'static', visibility: 'visible', display: 'none' });
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KYWs8/1/)

There were two things I had to tweak with the html and css:

(1)  I added an empty div for 'form-show-item-3' so there would be a div for each radio button. Otherwise, the code would have to be more complicated.

(2) I added the following styling. Otherwise, the margin of the `<p>` element inside the content div extends outside the div and the height jumps at the end of the animation.

```
div.dinamic-form-content {
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the animate method of jQuery for smooth transition.

```
$("main-form-show").animate({
     //you code here
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: Sorry I cant view it in my mobile..The animate method takes an argument of the speed. (shown in the link I pasted) Just reduce the speed